# Remap Windows-Key on Apple USB Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using a wired Apple-USB-Keyboard on my Windows 10 Notebook: [image: Apple Keyboard]

On the Apple-Keyboard, the Alt and Command Keys (= Windows Key) are switched. The bottom row is

`Ctrl | Alt | Cmd (Win) |   Space   | Cmd (Win) | Alt | Ctrl`

I'd like to remap them **only on the USB Keyboard**, so the Layout is similar to my Notebook's Layout:

`Ctrl | Cmd (Win) | Alt |   Space   | Alt | Cmd (Win) | Ctrl`

Tools I'v tried:

- [Randyrant's Sharpkeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html) from [this answer from 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/90036/mapping-apple-keyboard-keys-to-windows-keys) does not support Windows 10
- [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) doesn't seem to support remapping only on a specific USB Keyboard.

I don't want to remap my Notebook-Keyboard too, only the Apple-USB-Keyboard. **Is there a tool I can use, with which I can remap a USB Keyboard's keys?**

If not: **Is there a way with which I can switch (custom) keyboard layouts, e.g. via icon in the taskbar?**

Comment: Any layout you choose is applied to each and every keyboard.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: So now you have two questions. I already hinted at the answer to the original one. Regarding the one in the update yes, as soon more than one layout is added, custom or not it really doesn't matter, there will be an icon in the system tray. Honestly, you need to understand how this things work and you still don't. What you want - different layout for the external keyboard - is not possible. Selecting from different layouts is and always as been possible, but unrelated. (cont.)

Comment: OSes aren't aware of what's printed on the keys. The OS merely "translates" a given code to a character according to what layout is selected at the moment and it doesn't (and can't) distinguish between the same code coming from the internal or the external one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use macros. This doesn't completely solve the issue and it may be a little delayed, but it does the job. AutoHotKey would be a great solution, and you can just disable the macro when you are using the notebook keyboard.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll try it right away and see if this fits my needs...

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/nomand/9bb9fac582e2191685804c2ab96e9916 for a working example.